# SwiftyGif Remote Gif is running but will not display

Tags: swift, animated-gif

For the life of me I can't get the GIF to display using the [SwiftyGif](https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif) library. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
var outgoingMessageView: UIImageView!

    outgoingMessageView = UIImageView(frame:
        CGRect(x: llamaView.frame.maxX - 50,
               y: llamaView.frame.minY + 75,
               width: bubbleImageSize.width,
               height: bubbleImageSize.height))
    outgoingMessageView.delegate = self

    if textIsValidURL == true {
        print("URL is valid")
        outgoingMessageView.image = bubbleImage
        let maskView = UIImageView(image: bubbleImage)
        maskView.frame = outgoingMessageView.bounds
        outgoingMessageView.mask = maskView
        outgoingMessageView.frame.origin.y = llamaView.frame.minY - 25
        let url = URL(string: text)
        outgoingMessageView.setGifFromURL(url, manager: .defaultManager, loopCount: -1, showLoader: true)
    } else {
        outgoingMessageView.image = bubbleImage
    }            
    // Set the animations
    label.animation = "zoomIn"
    //outgoingMessageView.animation = "zoomIn"

    // Add the Subviews
    view.addSubview(outgoingMessageView)
    print("outgoingMessageView added")
```

The delegate lets me know it runs successfully via:

gifDidStart
gifURLDidFinish

Checking outgoingMessageView.isAnimatingGif() tells me it's still running.
Checking outgoingMessageView.isDisplayedInScreen(outgoingMessageView) tells me it's not being displayed

It "finishes" almost immediately, but it's the same in the example project, yet the gif still loops and displays in the project. I've changed loop counts, imageviews, not running via a mask as I intended and instead just a UIImageView, changed the GIF urls, all to no avail. Is this problem related to my view structure?

I am calling this function based on actions in a collectionView.[Image Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uliWR.png)

Using the latest SwiftyGIF version.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a sample about this with the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    testSwiftyGif()
}

public func testSwiftyGif() {

    let imgPath = "https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif/blob/master/SwiftyGifExample/1.gif?raw=true"
    let imgUrl = URL(string: imgPath)!

    var outgoingMessageView: UIImageView!

    outgoingMessageView = UIImageView(frame:
        CGRect(x: llamaView.frame.maxX - 50,
               y: llamaView.frame.minY + 75,
               width: 200,
               height: 200))

    outgoingMessageView.setGifFromURL(imgUrl, manager: .defaultManager, loopCount: -1, showLoader: true)

    self.view.addSubview(outgoingMessageView)
    print("outgoingMessageView added")

}
```

And it adds the gif as intended:
[image]

Aparently the issue is your view structure. The image is being added to the view, but the view is not visible due mask, frame or superview position.

Try to check the view hierarchy using the [xCode View Hierarchy Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help @alxlives, this narrows down the potential issues however the outgoingMessageView is at the top of the view structure and the actual image I use to build the mask displays properly, as well as any image (not gif) that I append. It's only when I .setGifFromURL that it doesn't work. I've attached an image to the question above.